# Cannot update state from render method React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a NavLink component like this:

```
<NavLink  isActive={(match, location) => this.isActiveFunc(match, location)}  className={classes.subLink} to={{ pathname: "/admin/users" }}>
    <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
       <ListItemText disableTypography={this.state.activePath === "/admin/users"} inset primary="Users" />
    </ListItem>
</NavLink>
```

and try to set my state every time the NavLink is active as follows:

```
 updateActivePath = (match) => {
    if (match && this.state.activePath !== match.path) {
      this.setState({activePath: match.path})
    }
  };

  isActiveFunc = (match, location) => {
    this.updateActivePath(match);
  };
```

This however gives me the following error:

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as
>   within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods
>   should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects
>   are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: is that NavLink from react-router?

Comment: It is from react-router-dom

Comment: why are you copying the active path to local state? just grab that active path from react-router-dom

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as my component is not within a <Route /> (it's the navigation bar that's always shown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "state" you're after is already in React Router, then copying it to your own state is unnecessary duplication, and the cause of your error (trying to update the state during `render`. You're better off just grabbing the state from the React Router. You can use a Route without a path for that

```
<Route render={({ location }) => (
   // this will render whenever the location changes
   <YourNavigationBar location={location} />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: This seems to do it! Thanks a lot for that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You use a setState in react lifecycle. You call your method updateActivePath in render or other lifecycle method react. This trigger an extra rendering for your component.

For fix this warning change your setState location in componentWillMount method or in function call by action (click, ...).

For must information go to lifecycle component documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: How would I get the current router path to the componentWillMount?

Comment: It looks like withRouter is the answer, but it appears to be depricated in v4

Comment: You can get a current router in your constructor, or you can use React-redux for create a router store. In this store you can stock many informations (currentRoute, previousRoute, ...), and you can get this information in your NavLink components.